# how to filter by node when looking at shards in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

How to filter by node when looking at shards in elastic search

`GET /_cat/shards?v` lists all the shards. I need to filter by a specific shard

Comment: Did you find a way to filter by node id?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [cat allocation API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-allocation.html#cat-allocation)

It provides a snapshot of the number of shards allocated to each data node and their disk space.

```
GET /_cat/allocation/<node_id>
```